# adding a class to text displayed by rails in the view

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, class

very straight forward..

how do I add a class to something like this

```
<h2><%= guide.title %></h2>
```

which is just displaying text?

Comment: What does `guide` represent and what does `title` represent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to wrap it within some container:

```
<div class="my_class"><%= guide.title %></div>
```

The container you'll use depends on the context given text is to be used.

### Update:

Since the text is already wrapped in `<h2>` you can do:

```
<h2 class='my_class'><%= guide.title %></h2>
```

### Another update:

If you wan to minimize the amount of pure html in your view, you can always do:

```
<%= content_tag :h2, class: 'my_class' do %>
  <%= guide.title %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This isn't just Rails.  HTML can't apply ids, styles and classes to text, it must be in some element.  If this is a title, the best element would be some kind of heading, eg. h2.

Comment: I am aware of that, however i remember using (or seeing) something like 
    <%= simple_form(guide.title), :class=> 'blah' %>

Comment: @rico_mac - The code above won't work. Most likely it was without parantheses: `simple_form_for guide.title, class: 'blah'`. You are executing then a method `simple_form_for` and passes a class as an argument, so the resulting html will include class in the form tag. If you are not executing any helper methods, you are just printing text and you can't add a class to the text.